# Does subqueries "short-circuit" based on other conditions?

Tags: oracle, performance, subquery

I have a slightly costly `case when exists (...) then 1 else 0 end` sub-query in the `select` clause. The sub-query is only really needed if another column in the main query has a specific value (can think of it as a has_child flag).

As the main query returns tens of thousands of rows and runs frequently, it's a prime target for optimisation.

I have tried adding `has_child = 1` into the `case when` clause, but that did not change the explain plan at all (understandably). But real query test feels quicker. Unfortunately, I cannot gather statistics on the production database, so I have no idea if the improvement is real or not.

So is Oracle actually able to skip/stop the join/sub-query if the condition guarding it is already false?

The explain plan looks like:
[image: explain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do.

```
select
  case 
    when (1 = 0 and (select 1/0 from dual) = 1) 
    then 1 
    else 0
  end as c 
from dual;

         C
----------
         0
```

Here `1 = 0` is false, so the second argument of the `AND` is not executed, luckily for us, because it would be a division by zero. With `1 = 1` the second part is executed and we receive the expected error:

```
select
  case 
    when (1 = 1 and (select 1/0 from dual) = 1) 
    then 1 
    else 0
  end as c 
from dual;

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

Comment: While you are correct that oracle chooses short circuiting in this case but I think that is mainly because 1=0 and 1=1 can be evaluated at compile time. If it wasn't 2 constants then it is not 100% guaranteed that oracle will do short circuiting every time. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900631/does-oracle-use-short-circuit-evaluation

Answer (score 1):

The oracle optimizer can chose to not execute part of the execution plan if it finds there's no rows to add.

If you join a table but don't select a column in there for instance, the optimizer will simply design a plan not even accessing the table you mentioned.

If it identifies that there's no rows to pull for a certain predicate, it may also decide to not run part of your query.

If you are able to run dbms_xplan.display_cursor() when you run the query (add it under your query) and run both together, you should see "Starts" column with a value of 0 for some of the execution plan steps.

If you run oracle 12c, the plan is now adaptive too which means it may change it's join type based on how much it was expecting to get and how much it's really getting during runtime.

Awesome stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Though `run dbms_xplan.display_cursor()` did not give me the "starts" column :(